# An idea about developing an agile wall web tool

Tags: java, agile

I'm thinking about developing a web app to visualize the agile wall. The reason is that the project I'm working in has multiple distributed teams, so it is very difficult to share the information on the agile wall across the teams. I know some tools like JIRA do have agile wall functionality built in, what I want to have is a dedicated agile wall web app which could potentially integrate with those popular project management systems.

Does this idea sound sensible and interesting to you? Please let me know if you get better idea about sharing the agile wall across distributed teams.

Thanks.
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how well the card wall translates to a small screen.  I've seen one similar implementation of something like this ([www.cardmeeting.com](http://www.cardmeeting.com)) that I was not impressed with.  One of the drawbacks to it is that the cards are unreadable until you click on them.  That being the case, the tools used by most commercial vendors to capture stories at least the advantage that you can immediately see the titles on the stories even if they don't implement the wall format.

Another concern that I have is trying to take a passive information radiator and insert it into an active presentation medium.  The wall format works partly (or even mainly, I haven't really looked at the research closely) because it's highly visible but not intrusive.  Whenever you see it you get an immediate snapshot of the current state of the project.  Translated into a web browser, you lose  this aspect.  It's not clear to me that in an active medium, where users need to navigate to information rather than simply absorb it, if the wall is still the right tool.

Comment: Thanks tvanfosson, I really agree with your comment.

A real story wall is hard to be translated by a browser screen as different projects can implement different walls.

But seems like a web based story wall is the only means for distributed teams, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Mingle](http://studios.thoughtworks.com/mingle-agile-project-management) from ThoughtWorks?

I haven't looked at it recently, but I'd expect it to be open to integration with other systems.

Even if you end up wanting to write your own, you should look at Mingle to see what a similar system looks like.

Comment: Also Rally, VersionOne, and SrumWorks.  Rally and Mingle seem to be the best of the offerings IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Simple-Kanban](http://www.simple-kanban.com/). All done in a single HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Before you start implementing your own tool, take a look at:
[http://www.userstories.com/products](http://www.userstories.com/products/)

I'm sure you can choose something appropriate :-)
Guess which one is ours...

Regards,
Marcin

Comment: Thanks Marcin, the link is very helpful. I'm not quite sure where is your product in the list, I think it might be on very top, 8).